# WearableListView with custom WearableListItemLayout don't show content

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I'm learning about Android Wear and I have to do a `listView` with custom layout.

I have this code for each item view of `ListView` with `linearLayout`.

```
<br.com.mobills.wear.views.WearableListItemLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
app:layout_box="all"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/contas_title"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="R$ 25,0000000"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>


</br.com.mobills.wear.views.WearableListItemLayout>
```

[image: list_item.xml]

But when I populate my adapter this happens:

[image: ListView Populate]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, each list item consists of an icon and a description. The Notifications sample implements a custom layout that extends LinearLayout to incorporate these two elements inside each list item. This layout also implements the methods in the [WearableListView.OnCenterProximityListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/WearableListView.OnCenterProximityListener.html) interface to change the color of the item's icon and fade the text in response to events from the [WearableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/WearableListView.html) element as the user scrolls through the list.

```
public class WearableListItemLayout extends LinearLayout
             implements WearableListView.OnCenterProximityListener {

    private ImageView mCircle;
    private TextView mName;

    private final float mFadedTextAlpha;
    private final int mFadedCircleColor;
    private final int mChosenCircleColor;

    public WearableListItemLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public WearableListItemLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public WearableListItemLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                  int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        mFadedTextAlpha = getResources()
                         .getInteger(R.integer.action_text_faded_alpha) / 100f;
        mFadedCircleColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.grey);
        mChosenCircleColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
    }

    // Get references to the icon and text in the item layout definition
    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        // These are defined in the layout file for list items
        // (see next section)
        mCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle);
        mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCenterPosition(boolean animate) {
        mName.setAlpha(1f);
        ((GradientDrawable) mCircle.getDrawable()).setColor(mChosenCircleColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNonCenterPosition(boolean animate) {
        ((GradientDrawable) mCircle.getDrawable()).setColor(mFadedCircleColor);
        mName.setAlpha(mFadedTextAlpha);
    }
}
```

For more information, check this document: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/lists.html

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me!

```
<br.com.mobills.wear.views.WearableListItemLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    app:layout_box="top|bottom"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_credit_card_white_24dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="adsfdsfasdfasdfasf sdf asdf asdf "
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="R$1000000"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: This is the result]